# How do you use BCCWJ properly?

Tags: discussion, resources

The Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese ([link](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/)) is a useful resource but I realized recently that I was not using it correctly. The searches I did on it seemed to produce different results to other users, so I knew I was doing something wrong. I was wondering if someone could provide an overview of the basics of searching for terms on that site - I am not experienced searching corpora even in English, so it can be even more confusing doing it in Japanese.

Very simple explanations and examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an account of 中納言?

Comment: @broccoliforest Yes I do

Comment: Oh, then it'll be surely complicated. It has a manual (Japanese) inside the logged-in site, but I don't think I grasped all the functions.

Answer (score 2):

The site I was using is very simple. Please check:

- You're visiting 少納言, the free un-parsed version: http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/search_form
- You're not using any quotes in the query box
- You have checked all the boxes under メディア/ジャンル and 期間

Comment: Well that is certainly easier than the one I was using!

Comment: Is this the current URL? https://shonagon.ninjal.ac.jp/